# R - Wordcloud from a simple dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, word-cloud

I have this simple dataframe:

```
    employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John  Doe','John Doe','John Doe')
    salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)


    df <- data.frame(employee, salary)
```

I want to create a wordcloud from the column employee and safe it as a png file.
I searched on google how to do this, but I don't get a simple wordcloud tutorial.

I my wordcloud "John" and "Doe" needs to be seperate words.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/wordcloud/versions/2.6/topics/wordcloud) and **TRY**. You will definitely get it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the salary column?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using `dplyr` to get your names into a vector before passing over to `wordcloud` as suggested in the comments:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(dplyr)


set.seed(123)


df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  select(-salary) %>% 
  separate(employee, into = c("e1", "e2")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.vector()


wordcloud(df1, min.freq = 1)
```

This give you:

[image]